# What are things to look for when choosing a raw cut of Steak?

Tags: steak

I'm guessing that when chefs go to the meat market early in the mornings to choose the best cuts of beef, they are doing it for a reason - what do they look for when judging raw beef that they will use for Steaks?

Answer (score 6):

A few things:

- grain fed vs corn fed vs grass fed.
  Each style lends their own flavour to
  the beef.

  - free range vs. feedlot. Cows fattened on feedlots will have more
    fat; the meat of free-range cows has
    a deeper flavour. Feedlot cows will
    also be more tender.
  - 'Organic' (a word with no meaning really) vs non. Some chefs are
    concerned with antibiotic and
    hormonal treatment of cows;
    *generally* speaking, something labeled 'organic' is less likely to
    have been chemically treated while
    alive.
  - marbling, the degree of intramuscular fat. More marbling =
    more flavour. Bear in mind of course
    that some cuts (e.g. tenderloin) have
    very little intramuscular fat.
  - aged or not, and wet vs. dry. Aging meat allows lactic acid to denature
    proteins and increase flavour. Dry
    aging is *significantly* better for
    this than wet. However, that comes at
    a cost, as dry-aged meats must be
    trimmed, resulting in a lower yield
    per initial pound of product.

Comment: "Organic", at least in the United States, does have a defined meaning when it comes to beef. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_beef

Answer (score 0):

target your desired flavor:

- if you want that marbled (naturally salty / fatty) flavor, best to seek a ribeye
- if you're more after the lean, your solution is a new york strip or a fillet
- if you require cheaper fare, afford what you can and tenderize it / spice it up

BAM!  or something

Comment: Personally for day to day cooking I like hangar steak. Nicely marbled, very beefy flavour, cooks quickly. I like to take a page from Nigella Lawson and sear it very hard, leaving it very rare, and served with Bearnaise.